# Looping through Named Range to Delete Contained Blank Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro to delete blank cells (value "", not empty as may contain formulas) in a named range, and am having trouble correcting run-time error '424', that an "Object [is] required."

```
Sub DeleteBlankCellsInANamedRange()
'Deletes empty cells in a named range (shifts cells up)

For Each c In Range("myNamedRange")
    If c.Value = 0 Then
        myNamedRange.Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp 'error 424 throws here
    End If
Next c
MsgBox "Macro completed"

End Sub
```

I figure the problem is with syntax, and have been trying different things without luck. Any ideas? Please share. Thanks for your help!

Comment: use `Option Explicit`. Use `Range("myNamedRange").Cells`  It could be either `"myNamedRange"` or `myNamedRange`. Use `c.Delete...`

Comment: Thanks @cyboashu ---Worked like a charm.

Comment: Actually @cyboashu, the macro deleted every cell in the range. The entire range is not blank. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I should say not every cell in the range is '0' (value), not blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub DeleteBlankCellsInANamedRange()
'Deletes empty cells in a named range (shifts cells up)

Dim rngCell     As Range
Dim rngDelete   As Range

For Each rngCell In Range("myNamedRange").Cells
    If rngCell.Value = 0 Then

        If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDelete = Union(rngDelete, rngCell)
        Else
            Set rngDelete = rngCell
        End If


    End If
Next

    If Not rngDelete Is Nothing Then
       rngDelete.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If

MsgBox "Macro completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @cyboashu ---Appreciate this very much, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The 'blank' cells I want to delete contain formulas, specifically conditional formulas that set their values to blank ("") given certain criteria.

Comment: if you want to delete `""` then use `If rngCell.Value = "" Then`